A system of equations on the symmetric group $S_5$
PROBLEM: Compute the number of triples $(f, g, h)$ of permutations on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that
$$f(g(h(x))) = h(g(f(x))) = g(x),$$
$$g(h(f(x)))=f(h(g(x))) = h(x),$$
$$h(f(g(x))) = g(f(h(x))) = f(x)$$
$\forall$ $x \in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
MY ATTEMPT:
Let $f \circ g$ represent the composition of permutations $f$ and $g$, where $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x)), \forall x \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$
Evaluating $f\circ g\circ h\circ f\circ h$ in two ways, we get:
$$f=g\circ f\circ h=(f\circ g\circ h)\circ f\circ h=f\circ g\circ h\circ f\circ h=f\circ (g\circ h\circ f)\circ h=f\circ h\circ h.$$
Thus, $h\circ h=1$, or, $h$ is the inverse of itself (involution). Similarly, we get $f$, $g$, and $h$ are all involutions. Then,
$$f\circ g\circ h=g \implies f\circ g=g\circ h.$$
So, $$f\circ g=g\circ h=h\circ f.$$
Let $x:= f\circ g=g\circ h=h\circ f.$ Then,
$$x^3=(f\circ g)\circ (g\circ h)\circ (h\circ f)=1.$$
Now, there should be two cases:
First, $x=1 \implies f=g=h$ is an involution... Then what? How can I find the number of such permutations?
Second, $x≠1 \implies ???$
I can't proceed any further.
How can I possibly find the number of triples?
Is this anyhow related to Group theory?
Can anyone give me some hints, or suggest better ways to approach this problem?
What should be the strategy, or what should be the first thing to come to one's mind when one encounters such problems?
Any help will be appreciated.

A very useful strategy is always to try some examples: try out some random permutations that fulfill the conditions you found and see if they work (or why they don't work). This will give you some inuition for the problem, and maybe you find already some solutions which you may be able to generalize.

You proved f, g, h are involutions as the first thing in your attempt, so it is confusing that you then ask "Can f, g, h be individually proved to be involutions?"

Some group theory would be helpful. In particular, it might be helpful to consider how permutations decompose into transpositions. Note that since $f^2 = g^2 = h^2 = 1$, these permutations decompose into a product of disjoint transpositions. Similarly, $x$ is either the identity or a $3$-cycle, since $x^3 = 1$ and this is $S^5$.
This should make counting much more straightforward.

Some group theory might be helpful. In particular, you should know that if $x^3 = 1$, then $x$ is either the identity, of the form $(123)$. If $x = 1$ then $f = g = h = 1$ so there is only one possible value of $x$. For the second, there are $2 \cdot \binom{5}{3} = 20$ choices for $x$.
Also, since $f^2 = g^2 = h^2 = 1$ as you noted, all of these decompose into a product of disjoint cycles.
If $x = 1$, then we have $f = g = h = 1$ as you observed. We also have $25$ more cases, though. In particular, $f$ can be any of the $\binom{5}{2}$ transposition, or any product of two disjoint transpositions, of which there are $5 \times 3$. All of these cases satisfy the initial equation.
If $x = (123)$ (or one of the other 19 3-cycles), then we could have $f = (13)$, $g = (12)$, and $h = (23)$, or one of the three cycles of this. We can also add a disjoint permutation to the end of each, (so $f=(13)(45)$, $g = (12)(45)$, $h = (23)(45)$, or one of the $3$ cycles of that). This gives us a total of $6$ cycles for each original 3-cycle.
So we get a total of
$$26 + (20)(2)(3) = 146$$
triples.
Edit: I have added the case I missed. $f = g = h$ does not imply $f = 1$, as I (incorrectly) suggested.

I don't know where/ what you did wrong, as the answer given is $146$. I don't understand how it is... anyway thanks for your time!

@FKcosθ apologies! I have fixed my solution.
To address some of your more general questions: when counting permutations satisfying a certain condition, decomposing into cycles/transpositions is often very helpful. But most of the times these calculations are just tedious.
